# What does enabling Google Developers Console actually do?

Tags: google-developer-tools

We have a request from a company doing work for one of our departments which would require us to enable the Developers Console in our Google Apps For Education domain.  I can find scant information on what turning this on actually does.

One of the things I did google up talked about setting up billing!  I surely don't want 40,000 students to be able run things at Google and send us the bill!!

Any ideas where I can educate myself on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's no big deal, there shouldn't be any issues. It will only charge you if you use google software that isn't free, but they should have to get past a password before they can do anything like that. I would also block the specific non-free applications, but apart from that, no big deal.